# How can I auto scroll when clicking on my nav bar to a specific part of my page?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to know if it's possible to auto-scroll when I'm clicking on my nav bar title right to a specific part of my page? Is it possible without using jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very much possible without the use of Javascript or Jquery. I've created a basic version of the behavior you're looking for. This is possible using `ids` in your HTML. Please see the example.

```css
a {
  font-size: 10rem;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
      <!-- potential navbar component -->
      <a href="#about">About</a><br>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1500/000/fff&text=I'm+a+dumb+image+simply+for+scroll+behavior.">
      <h1 id="about">About</h1> <!-- goes to this spot of page because of id -->
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/1500/000/fff&text=I'm+a+dumb+image+simply+for+scroll+behavior.">
</div>
```

Comment: Cool, thank you! Is it possible to have it scroll smoothly or is this functionality only for jQuery use ?

Comment: @Softee Yes, you can add `scroll-behavior: smooth;` to your HTML in CSS. See the changes.

Comment: I just tested on my html code and it works like a charm ! The only thing I have a problem with is that it always stops under the title and I don't really understand why ? Is it possible to "tell" the scroll where to exactly stop ?

Comment: @Softee It will stop where ever your `ID` is located that is associated with the `href` I would suggest adding the `#id` on the title where you want it to stop. Typically, the `ID` associated will be at the very top after you click and it scrolls.

Comment: I did add it to my title but it always stops a bit below. I'm doing this on a onepage website with stick navbar

Comment: https://codepen.io/Softee/pen/RwLaJye
There you go, you can click on "GUIDES ET ASTUCES" in the navbar to see the problem. 
And thanks, I did ! I'm new here trying to understand what it does and everything on here lol

Comment: @Softee Everythings working properly just seems your fixed navbar is covering the title. Easy fix. Check out this [codepen](https://codepen.io/kameronmayers/pen/GRMZGYe)  and the additions I made to your HTML. All I did was remove the `id` on the `h2` and added another div at the start of the content with that id. `<div id="guides"><br></div>` check the changes!